# Return record only for the first match on Oracle SQL query with JOIN that have multiple "OR" conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

First one only with id field:

```
CREATE TABLE a_test (id_test VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO a_test VALUES ('AAA');
INSERT INTO a_test VALUES ('BBB');
INSERT INTO a_test VALUES ('CCC');
```

Second table with 3 columns, which can have id_test of the first a_test table referenced  in one of the columns OR in multiple columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy_test (id_first VARCHAR2(20), id_second VARCHAR2(20), id_third VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO dummy_test VALUES ('AAA', 'test', 'test');
INSERT INTO dummy_test VALUES ('test', 'test', 'BBB');
INSERT INTO dummy_test VALUES ('CCC', 'AAA', 'test');
INSERT INTO dummy_test VALUES ('test', 'BBB', 'CCC');
INSERT INTO dummy_test VALUES ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
```

In the final query i need to return `a_test.id_test, dummy_test.*` with the following logic

- If `a_test.id_test = dummy_test.id_first` match then return that row without checking `dummy_test.id_second , dummy_test.id_third`
- If `a_test.id_test = dummy_test.id_first` does not match, then check `a_test.id_test = dummy_test.id_second`, if match, return row without checking the third row.
- Same with the third case.

I am little bit stuck with the query. In this case the return should be:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: Yes, believe me i tried a lot of options that i found on internet. 

I tried to write JOIN with OR conditions for each case with different combinations. Also make a UNION with each condition, but it give me records for each match, and that is not what i am looking for. Can´t paste it now, because i am on different PC. Will do tomorrow. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `ROW_NUMBER` window function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT A.*, B.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY B.ROWID 
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN A.ID_TEST = B.ID_FIRST THEN 1
                                WHEN A.ID_TEST = B.ID_SECOND THEN 2
                                ELSE 3 END) AS RN
  FROM A_TEST A 
  JOIN DUMMY_TEST B ON A.ID_TEST = B.ID_FIRST OR A.ID_TEST = B.ID_SECOND 
                    OR A.ID_TEST = B.ID_THIRD
) T WHERE RN = 1;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T9a7Hwpq)

Comment: First of all thanks all for the answers. 

All the answers are correct but i think the ORA-01017 is the shorter and clear version of the solution so i will check it as valid one. 

In the real world case, i finally managed to get same data from other source using multiple tables.

In "real world" case i managed to get the result with different approach using different tables.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative not using unions (not necessarily better than the ones offered):

```
with a_test as
(select  *
 from (VALUES ('AAA'), ('BBB'), ('CCC')) T(id_test)
 ), 
 dummy_test as (
 select *
 from (values ('AAA', 'test', 'test')
, ('test', 'test', 'BBB')
, ('CCC', 'AAA', 'test')
, ('test', 'BBB', 'CCC')
, ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')) T(id_first , id_second , id_third )
)
select a.id_test
    , case when d1.id_first is not null then d1.id_first 
           when d2.id_second is not null then d2.id_first
           when d3.id_third is not null then d3.id_first
      end as id_first
    , case when d1.id_first is not null then d1.id_second
           when d2.id_second is not null then d2.id_second
           when d3.id_third is not null then d3.id_second
      end as id_second
    , case when d1.id_first is not null then d1.id_third
           when d2.id_second is not null then d2.id_third
           when d3.id_third is not null then d3.id_third
      end as id_second

from a_test a

     left join
     dummy_test d1
     on d1.id_first=a.id_test
     
     left join
     dummy_test d2
     on d2.id_second=a.id_test
     and d1.id_first is null

     left join
     dummy_test d3
     on d3.id_third=a.id_test
     and d1.id_first is null
     and d2.id_second is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; I hope someone else posts better one, as I don't like it particularly.

Sample data; I expanded `dummy_test` table with another row whose values don't exist in `a_test` at all and should be - I presume - skipped. I also added `rn` column into `dummy_test` for sorting purposes; it isn't used elsewhere.

```
SQL> select * from a_test;

ID_TEST
--------------------
AAA
BBB
CCC

SQL> select * from dummy_test order by rn;

        RN ID_FIRST             ID_SECOND            ID_THIRD
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 AAA                  test                 test
         2 test                 test                 BBB
         3 CCC                  AAA                  test
         4 test                 BBB                  CCC
         5 AAA                  BBB                  CCC
         6 XXX                  YYY                  ZZZ

6 rows selected.
```

Query uses 3 CTEs, each of them joining tables on the first, second or third `ID` value and - at the same time - skipping rows whose values have already been collected in previous CTE. Final result is union of these 3 CTEs:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 as
  3    (select a.id_test, b.*
  4     from dummy_test b join a_test a on a.id_test = b.id_first
  5    ),
  6  t2 as
  7    (select a.id_test, b.*
  8     from dummy_test b join a_test a on a.id_test = b.id_second
  9     where not exists (select null from t1
 10                       where t1.id_first = b.id_first)
 11    ),
 12  t3 as
 13    (select a.id_test, b.*
 14     from dummy_test b join a_test a on a.id_test = b.id_third
 15     where not exists (select null from t2
 16                       where t2.id_second = b.id_second)
 17    )
 18  select * from t1
 19  union
 20  select * from t2
 21  union
 22  select * From t3
 23  order by 2
 24  /
```

Result:

```
ID_TEST                      RN ID_FIRST             ID_SECOND            ID_THIRD
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
AAA                           1 AAA                  test                 test
BBB                           2 test                 test                 BBB
CCC                           3 CCC                  AAA                  test
BBB                           4 test                 BBB                  CCC
AAA                           5 AAA                  BBB                  CCC

SQL>
```